# How to cast a List object of chars in an Array of chars?

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, list

How to convert or make a cast of a List object typized as a container of chars like

```
Dim mylist As List(Of Char) = New List(Of Char)(New Char() {"1"c, "2"c})
```

in a simple array of chars as

```
Dim mychars() As Char
```

without make a loop for...

thank you

Max

Comment: Here you go :): List.ToArray http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx

Comment: thanks!  toArray() method make the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [`List(Of T).ToArray` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx)?

For example:

```
Dim myChars() as Char = myList.ToArray()
```